# Discord.py DM command (To send and recieve a dm)

Tags: discord.py, bots, dm

I'm pretty new to python and well, I wanted to make a discord bot that sends a dm, and when the other user receives the dm, they answer back, and the owner of the code or an admin of a server will be able to see what it says!

Here is my code so **far** for the dm:

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message):
    await user.send(message)
```

How do I make it so that i can see what the user replied to the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use `client.wait_for()` with `check()`, so add this after `await user.send(message)`:

```
def check(msg):
        return msg.author == user and isinstance(msg.channel, discord.DMChannel)#check for what the answer must be, here the author has to be the same and it has to be in a DM Channel
    try:
        answer = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=600.0)#timeout in seconds, optional
        await ctx.send(answer.content)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       await author.send("Your answer time is up.")#do stuff here when the time runs out
```

all if this is **in** your `dm` function.

References:

[wait_for(event, *, check=None, timeout=None)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just gotta fix the indents and im all ready to go!